# Rails 4 Routing within Namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, namespaces

I am trying to set the base address *www.myplace.com/admin* to be directed to *www.myplace.com/admin/adminhub* within the namespace coding below. I have tried every combination I can think of, but to no avail. I was trying to follow the same code used for the / of the app.

```
namespace :admin do
    ...
    get "adminhub"
    get 'admin', to: 'adminhub'

  end
```

Comment: base address? you mean root?

Comment: No, I am trying to set _www.myplace.com/admin_ to resolve to _www.myplace.com/admin/adminhub_. Within the namespace.

Comment: You could put a redirect in admin/admin_controller#admin `redirect_to "/admin/adminhub", status: 301`. It isn't best practice, but it seems that train left the station long ago :)

Comment: You mean this `get '/admin', to 'admin#adminhub'`?

Comment: @Pavan when I put that in and restart my server it errors out giving me: 'rb:84: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
    get '/sekret', to 'sekret#adminhub''

Comment: @NickM What would be the best practice? What am I missing? I am still quite the newb in this.

Comment: What is the name of your controller? because both `get "adminhub"` and `get 'admin', to: 'adminhub'` is not valid when inside a namespace.

Comment: The syntax error is due to this `'sekret#adminhub''`. It should be `'sekret#adminhub'`

Comment: @Pavan that second ' was my attempt to set it as code in the reply, it is not in the actual code.

Comment: My mistake it should be `get '/admin', to: 'admin#adminhub'`

Comment: Best practice would probably be to set a `root:` and set `before_actions` with redirects, but it's hard to say without knowing what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to redirect the browser to the new URL. You can do this with the `redirect` helper in the routes.

```
get '/admin', to: redirect('/admin/adminhub')
```

This allows you to redirect from one path to another. See the [Redirection section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection) in the Rails Routing Guide for more details.

Comment: I got this to work with: `get '', to: redirect('/admin/adminhub')` from within the namespace code. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. You might also be able to more that outside the namespace block if you don't want the awkward `get ''`